# "__u8 b[16]" vs "unsigned char uuid_t[16]"

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Is there any difference between the following constructs

1.

```
#define UUID_SIZE 16

typedef struct {
  __u8 b[UUID_SIZE];
} uuid_t;
```

2.

```
typedef unsigned char uuid_t[16];
```

To my untrained eye they appear to be saying the same thing. If they aren't, please can someone enlighten me on the difference? If they are the same, is there a reason to prefer one over the other?

(Background here is the first is from the Linux kernel and the second is from a module I'm trying to load into the kernel. The module doesn't load because of the typedef conflict on uuid_t. I'm hoping if the second one is the same as the first I can just remove the line from the module otherwise I'll need to rename it everywhere).

Comment: Second version is not copyable, it also decays to a pointer under certain circumstances. First version is instead a struct and doesn't behave like the second. It all depends on how you plan to use it, but the differences are there.

Comment: @DeiDei but would it be OK to let my kernel module use what is already defined in the kernel or should I just rename it everywhere in the kernel module?

Comment: Note it looks like the kernel module just uses a uuid for logging and as an identifier in some messages.

Comment: One is a struct type containing an array member and the other is an array type, so there are bound to be source changes in your module to avoid the conflict. If you change your module to use the kernel's `uuid_t` then please note that the kernel's `uuid_t` has only been there since kernel version 4.13 (before that it was called `uuid_be`).